# How to ensure primary/foreign key match in two tables on insertion?

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

I have Order and OrderLine tables in my access database.

When I enter each OrderLine I would need to enter the matching OrderNo, but how when I don't know the OrderNo in a C# application?

For example I would insert the CustomerNo and OrderDate into the Order table and the OrderNo will be auto assigned. Now I want to insert each item into the OrderLine table but I don't know the OrderNo of that Order to sync it all together?

Comment: This is too vague, can you provide the table structure of the tables in question ?

Comment: I don't how in Access but in SQL you get the new ID via @identity.